# How the JMeter script can return 0/1 = pass/fail on the command line?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to run a JMeter load test from command line and I want the test should return only pass or fail result to command line. In a test plan I have 6-7 samplers. How to do this? There is one option in Thread Group, 'Action to be taken after a sampler error'. How to return its value to command line?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which will return error status to command line:

```
 System.exit(1);
```

Execute in command line and you will get

```
errorlevel=1
```